# Div overlapping issue

Tags: css, html

I have divs as shown in the [FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/k8Vut/) , the div content gets overlapped with the header resulting in hiding of the content data ie "Sample data 1".

```
<div id="header">
<div id="firstdiv">
    <table border="0px" width="100%" style="background-color:rgb(2, 44, 72)">
                        <tr>
                            <td id="test1" style="width:90%;" align="left">test

                            </td>
                        </tr>
                    </table>
</div>

</div>
<div id="content">
<table border="0">
    <tr>
        <td>Sample data 1
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Sample data 2
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Sample data 3
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Sample data 4
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
</div>
```

//CSS
    #header
    {
    position:relative;
    }
    #firstdiv
    {
    float:left;width:100%;
    position:absolute;
    color:white;
    }

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add some padding to header: http://jsfiddle.net/k8Vut/3/

```
   #header
   {
       padding-top: 25px;
   }
```

Since your `firstdiv` is absolute it'll start from top: 0 position and hence overwrites the relative positioned header. So if you add some padding, it'll move the header a little below and make space for `firstdiv`

Comment: This is more like removing the consequences rather than the cause.

Comment: We don't know what the whole code is. Considering OP might have a reason for positioning it absolute

Comment: Agreed, it was a bold assumption based on instinct. :)

Comment: hmm..Though OP should have resolved the issue by now. Since he's not replying :)

Comment: Probably trying to see which solution fits better. :)

Comment: Thanks guys, It worked, yes i have a reason for putting absolute. Cheers

Comment: Then you should select this answer.

Answer (score 2):

Remove the absolute positioning from the `#firstdiv` element. The left float also seems unnecessary.

See here: http://jsfiddle.net/k8Vut/2/